# Ньюанс по дженерикам

Tags: java, ide, generics

Вопрос может показаться крайне простым, однако, самую очевидную информацию, порой, бывает сложно "загуглить". 
В пример предложу инициацию ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Стоит ли указывать тип хранимых в списке объектов еще и в правой части выражения, в угловых скобках? Какова роль такой двойной инициализации. Часто, в чужом коде, вижу и подобную запись:

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Однако, IDE подчеркивает второй "String" серым цветом, и указывает, что тип можно второй раз не указвать вообще. Но, если такая возможность существует, значит бывают ситуации, когда это необходимо. Прошу объяснить, когда.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870173/what-are-the-list-or-arraylist-declaration-differences-in-java второй ответ

Comment: благодарю, вопрос решен

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это так называемый оператор diamond (бриллиант, алмаз). Введен в Java SE 7. Он называется так, потому что чем-то похож на камень: <>.

до Java 7

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

после Java 7

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Включение оператора алмазов (<>) в Java SE 7 означает, что код, который создает универсальные классы может быть более компактным и удобочитаемым.

Так что не обязательно указывать тип хранимых в списке объектов еще и в правой части выражения, в угловых скобках.